# I've got nodejs installed but trying to run code in the terminal shows error "can't find module"

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

VScode error message saying shell integration not activated

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your Screenshot:

1. The javascript file is located at `~/Documents/MY PROJECTS/hello.js`.
2. You are trying to run a hello.js file in `~`.

`~` would be `EDWIN` in your case.

Since Node js can't find the `hello.js` file it throws an error. Locate the correct directory with `cd Documents/MY PROJECTS` and then try to run the js file via `node hello.js`